# fire event only from user request

Tags: c#, wpf, events, ischecked

Is the any way to make `Checked` and `Unchecked` only fire when button clicked by user?

`IsChecked` is bound to `Playing` property. This value may change from background (not by user). So it causes Checked and Unchecked events to fire again and conflict with other things.

When ever I try to write code to fix this it becomes real mess. Thanks for your help.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="TogglePlay" Width="90"
              Style="{DynamicResource TogglePlay}" 
              IsChecked="{Binding SessionData.Playing}"
              Checked="TogglePlay_Checked" Unchecked="TogglePlay_OnUnchecked"/>
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TogglePlay" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked , ElementName=TogglePlay}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Play" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked , ElementName=TogglePlay}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Pause" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use binding mode "OneWayToSource"

Comment: Thanks. this does fix most problems. one problem is that when player stops from background, button content is not updated.

Comment: Try to bind Content property in TwoWay/OneWay mode and IsChecked property in OneWayToSource mode.

Comment: Maybe in your situation, you shoud disable IsChecked binding, and just bind Content.

Comment: Actualy, you should understand that commonly you shouldn't use events in XAML, this is not WPF way.